# JQuery. По клику на radiobutton изменять value по кругу

Tags: jquery, form, input, radiobutton

В форме несколько радиобаттонов (можно заменить на любой другой элемент формы - главное, чтобы можно было отправить на бэк нужные значения value).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 $('.buttons .clicker').on('click', function() {
    //
  });
  
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: crimson;
  position: relative; // важно
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.buttons + .buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.clicker {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pin {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div class='buttons'>
  <input type='radio' value='pin1' name='option1' checked class="pin" />
  <div class="clicker"></div> <!-- этот блок перекрывает на абсолюте все баттон, чтобы клик был на него а не на баттон -->
</div>

<div class='buttons'>
  <input type='radio' value='pin1' name='option2' checked class="pin" />
  <div class="clicker"></div> <!-- этот блок перекрывает на абсолюте все баттон, чтобы клик был на него а не на баттон -->
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lavrov/b2y7rxzt/29/

Задача в том, что таких блоков с инпутом несколько. У каждого может быть три значения (например value1, value2, value3). Нужно по клику на каждый баттон (в коде я его перекрыл .clicker - мне кажется лучше кликать на него, но не уверен) изменять по кругу его value с value1 на value2, потом на value3, затем снова на value1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, первое, что пришло в голову.
Поправьте если не прав или не так понял задачу.

Добавьте для элементов атрибуты data-value1, data-value2 итд
При клике получайте нужный вам атрибут и записывайте его в value.
Условие перехода на новый круг простым счётчиком и if.